# Sorting Multiple Objects By Member in Descending Order?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I've had a look at the following question : Sorting a vector of objects by a property of the object

And it seems very relevant to my case. I have a small number of Player objects (6-10), and they all have information such as their name, and several relevant stats. I want to sort them in descending order by one particular stat.

Still very confused about what the

Help please!

**EDIT: FULL UPDATED CODE BELOW**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 class Player {
 public:
Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int& diceRoll);

int calcInitiative(int& diceRoll);

int diceRoll;

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Player& player) {
    return out << player.mName << " " << player.mInitiative; 
    }

bool operator<(const Player& rhs) const {

 if(mInitiative < rhs.mInitiative) return true;

     if(mInitiative > rhs.mInitiative) return false;

     if(mInitiative == rhs.mInitiative) return false;

}

int mDex, mMod, mLvl, mInitiative;
 string mName;
 };

Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int& diceRoll)
: mName(name), mDex(Dex), mMod(Mod), mLvl(Lvl)
{}


 int Player::calcInitiative(int& diceRoll) {

return (mLvl/2) + mDex + mMod + diceRoll;
 }

 int main() {

 int rollD, rollS; // etc.

 vector<Player> playerVec;

 cout << "Derek rolled: ";
 cin >> rollD;
 cout << '\n' << "Scott rolled: ";
 cin >> rollS;

// etc.


Player Derek("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);
Player B("B", 2, 0, 9, rollB);

// etc...

Derek.mInitiative = Derek.calcInitiative(rollD);
Scott.mInitiative = Scott.calcInitiative(rollS);

//etc.

playerVec.push_back(Derek);
playerVec.push_back(Scott);

// etc.

cout << "The initative order is: " << '\n';

sort (playerVec.begin(), playerVec.end());

for(vector<Player>::iterator it = playerVec.begin(); it != playerVec.end(); ++it) {
cout << *it << endl;
}

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you only ever want to sort by one combination of properties, just overload < and be done with it.

Comment: std::sort uses the Quicksort algorithm for sorting

Comment: Overloading the < operator, at least in the way that was suggested below, has given me some difficulty trying to cout statements after the fact. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rome_Leader: And as is being clarified in that question, `operator<` has _nothing_ to do with your difficulty with `cout` statements.

Comment: It keeps cutting off my explanation, but basically, still struggling to figure out what is going on with operator<, and the compiler breaks and throws an error when I run it, saying the operator< is invalid, but if I force continue, the values print perfectly, except backwards.

Comment: @Rome_Leader: I've updated my answer to answer your new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have all the code written already.

In your Player class, add the following function:

```
bool operator<(const Player& rhs) const;
```

and make it return true if `this` is less than the right-hand-side. Similar to your last code block.

Now run:

```
sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
```

That will do an in-place sort.

**Edit:** Here's a fully compilable example to show how it all works together:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
        Player(int stat1, int stat2) : m_stat1(stat1), m_stat2(stat2) {}

        bool operator<(const Player& rhs) const {
                if(m_stat1 < rhs.m_stat1) return true;
                if(m_stat1 > rhs.m_stat1) return false;
                return m_stat2 < rhs.m_stat2;
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Player& player) {
                return out << player.m_stat1 << ", " << player.m_stat2;
        }

private:
        int m_stat1, m_stat2;
};

int main()
{
        vector<Player> aPlayers;
        aPlayers.push_back(Player( 1, 2 ));
        aPlayers.push_back(Player( 1, 1 ));
        aPlayers.push_back(Player( 5, 0 ));

        std::sort(aPlayers.begin(), aPlayers.end());

        for(vector<Player>::iterator it = aPlayers.begin();
                        it != aPlayers.end(); ++it)
        {
                cout << *it << endl;
        }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1, 1
1, 2
5, 0
```

I put operator<< in there since you mentioned it in your comment, but it really has nothing to do with sorting. std::sort() will work just fine without it.

**Edit 2**: With your new code, you mention that the compiler is giving you an error. That error is likely because it can't be certain that the code will return a value. If you add `return false` to the end of `operator<`, it will stop giving you an error. That would also make the third line in your `operator<` redundant.

As far as the results being in reverse order, `sort` sorts in ascending order by default. There's a couple really simple ways to resolve this. The most obvious is to rewrite `operator<` to generate the ordering your would prefer. A more general option is to feed reverse iterators into std::sort instead of the default iterators:

```
std::sort(aPlayers.rbegin(), aPlayers.rend());
```

`rbegin()` and `rend()` are just like `begin()` and `end()`, except they go in reverse.

Comment: Ahh I see! So this overload, in conjunction with my other overload, will prevent switching in the cases of the elements already being in the right order!

Comment: You don't need any other overload, just `operator<`. std::sort will automatically do the rest for you; whenever it finds two elements that are out of order, it calls std::swap on those two elements, and you end up with a vector that's in order.

Comment: Still having some difficulty. Since the overload, the double angle brackets (<<) for cout no longer work. Do I need to make a separate overload for them now? Also, maybe I am a little unclear on the syntax, but in typing the operator< overload, my second parameter should be any player. Typing rhs doesn't seem to cut it syntax wise.

Comment: @Rome_Leader: Did the sample in the question clarify your confusion?

Comment: I'm definitely getting there. Very helpful. I'm still pretty fuzzy on what's going on with the < operator though. More details in original post in a second. In the future, I should post the full project to date instead of little bits that I'm having trouble with, so I can explain the whole picture.

Comment: Mostly, while I'm looking at it, I think it's comparing two values from the same player. I want to compare values from two different players (the same data member).

Answer (score 2):

By calling std::sort on a vector with a provided predicate (in your case this is a functor) you are already swapping your players.

In your sample after calling sort on myVec you will have your vector of of Player, or what ever T is sorted by the property x in a descending order.

So I see no purpose of switching / swapping anything manually.

Comment: So you contend that a sort call like above, sorting by Player's property .stat will switch the objects themselves in place anyway? That would be very useful if so. Then I could simply output their .stat values to the user in order.

Comment: Well that's exactly the use of sort.
As Rick pointed out, replace the functor with a operator< in your Player class will allow sorting in a much easier way.

Comment: Ahh, OK. Sorry for my confusion. I'm unable to test now, but I think it should work out, and be a great improvement over my previous attempts.